# Does Libgdx being "for Desktop" mean dependency-free native executables?

Tags: java, libgdx, platform, distribution

I want to clarify whether the Java Framework "LibGDX" can be used to compile games to native executables. The description/tagline says "Desktop/Android/HTML5/iOS Java game development framework".

I presumed that when they say "desktop", what is meant is native executables and not that they'll be `.jar` that needs JVM/Java installed on the native machine to run.

Can Libgdx games run without a Java dependency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means desktop.

You have two options to deploy your libGDX app to the desktop:

- Create a self-runnable JAR. This is easier (Eclipse can export it pretty easily).
- Create an EXE, via [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) (or some other wrapper). This is possible too (especially with Gradle).

I've used both approaches and they work equally well as far as I can tell.

Both rely on Java being installed. You still need a JVM; there's no way around it.

Launch4j also includes an option to bundle a JRE with your app, which would make it a "true" standalone application (doesn't need Java installed on the user's PC). Your app will be quite big, though.